# Honda Accord 8th Generation clicking on turn

Tags: honda, axle

I have had clicking during turning with Honda  Accord for three years. It's frequency of noise does increase year from year. Brought to new mechanic one year again. He did say, eventually "axle", passenger or driver, will need repair.

I have read about CV joints and full axle repairs.
When does this *need* to be repaired?
What actually is *being* repaired? Online it states "full replacement" is better than "individual parts" replacement.
Diagrams appreciated. Replacement est with parts and labors appear to be around $500, accurate?

Comment: Roughly where is the clicking coming from?

Comment: engine compartment , maybe right front